# how to decode amr files using c#.net

Tags: c#-4.0, audio, naudio, ms-media-foundation, amr

I need to decode amr format to pcm format, which is later converted to mp3 using c#.net. But I am hardly finding any library to do so. It seems with NAudio it is not possible. Is there any c# based open source library which can be used to decode this format files?. Presently I am working on windows server 2012(64 bit).

NAudio Code:

```
public void Decode() 
{
 .....
 var result= new MediaFoundationReader("..\\sample.amr");
 // later converted to  mp3 here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks you two guys are doing the same thing: [How to convert amr files to mp3 using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20344191/how-to-convert-amr-files-to-mp3-using-c-sharp)

You typically need to have a [third party] AMR decoder installed and integrated into Windows API (ACM, DirectShow, Media Foundation). Then you will use your favorite library around this API, such as NAudio.

Example of AMR decoder: [MONOGRAM AMR Pack](http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/2008/03/16/monogram-amr-pack-1010/).

Answer (score 0):

You're unlikely to find a C# decoder for AMR files. I'd recommend just finding a command-line utility that you can call to convert to PCM. For example, it looks like [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) can be used to decode AMR.